# Resources becoming mixed in Android Studio 1.5.1 using Gradle2.0.0-BETA2

Tags: android, android-studio

Weird problem that happens only occasionally (couple of times a day), and is fixed by cleaning the project and rebuilding:

[image]

As you can see, in some builds text resources are scrambled and worse, res ID's and image ids can also be every so slightly wrong causing weird app wide problems during testing (View's not being found in findViewById() for instance).

I assumed it was because of Gradle2.0.0-ALPHA4 but it's also in evidence in BETA2 - so I'm posting this question in case that's a red herring (I need to use these in order to use the individual Google Services Libraries).

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Why not use the AS Beta 2.0 when you use the beta build-plugin?

Comment: Switching from a Stable AS version to a beta version seems counter intuitive to fix a problem (and will likely bring with it several new ones).

Comment: you are using the beta of the build-plugin - then you should also use the beta of AS - another option is to use stable build plugin and stable AS - but your mix is bad ..

Comment: I can't use a stable gradle version - the latest (stable) Google Play services depends on it (for some reason)

Answer (score 0):

Please update your Gradle, even the emulator. 
And Then Update your AndroidStudio to Android Studio 2.0 in the Beta Channel (The canary Channel is least stable)

Comment: I'm not using an Emulator. And Grade.2.0.0-BETA2 is the latest version available. Using a beta version rather than a stable version of AS seems counter intuitive - unless you have specific knowledge it's a bug in AS 1.5.1?